# Magento 2: Change error message on checkout "An error occurred on the server. Please try again"

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, messages, magento-2.1.4, global-messages

**Preconditions**

Magento 2.1.4

PHP 7

Production mode

**Steps to reproduce**

Wanted to change the generic "An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again" to "We could not place this order. Please call us to complete."
Changed the text in vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php
Cleared the static files, re-deployed static files, cleaned and flushed the cache. Also re-compiled for good measure.

**Expected result**

When an error occurs in checkout the error message should read "We could not place this order. Please call us to complete."

**Actual result**

Same error message occurs everytime "An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again."

**Has anyone successfully changed the error message at checkout, to their own custom message?**